# Change dtype of weights for pytorch pretrained model

Tags: pytorch, yolo, dtype

I am using YOLOV7 model. The pretrained weights shared are optimised and shared in float16 dtype.
How can I convert the dtype of parameters of model in PyTorch. I want to convert the type of the weights to float32 type.

```
weights = torch.load('yolov7-mask.pt')
model = weights['model']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load weights to your model and just call `.float()`.

example:

```
cp = torch.load('yolov7-mask.pt')
model.load_state_dict(cp['weight'])
model = model.float()
```

It'll work if the model's class is `nn.Module`. (Checked for torch version 1.8)